# iOS Enterprise distribution error - "cannot connect to server"?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have three iOS enterprise apps on our internet server, and our users have been downloading OTA just fine until today. All of a sudden, I get this message:

[image]
Our IT guys have been scrambling to make sure there's nothing wrong with the server. Everything checks out. The .PLIST files and the .IPA files and their locations have not changed.

I updated the iOS in my phone to 8.2, the error is still there.

I remember a while back that Apple decreed that the install files must be served from an SSL directory, which I discovered after a similar problem occurred. We have since fixed that and everything has been hunky-dory until today. Has Apple made some other change like that? I can't find anything on the Apple Developer's page that addresses that. Hoping someone else has been luckier than I.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you connect to the URL from a web browser?  Were you using export grade certificates/ciphers that have been turned off by a recent patch?

Comment: Yes, the page that contains the download link is in the same folder as the .plist, so it is accessible through a browser, either inside the network or outside the network. I am not an IT person, so the certificate/cipher question is foreign to me.

Comment: Can you access a file on that server from safari on the iOS device?

Comment: yes,, the website is working fine otherwise, including another SSL page that we have on it.

Comment: Can you connect the device to a machine running Xcode and check the device logs when you try and install the app?

Comment: Give me a minute and I'll see. [Update] Paul, the device log says "No Device Logs"

Comment: You should always be able to view the "live" console - go to the "devices" window in Xcode and select the device on the left.  The console is at the bottom - you may need to click the little triangle in the bottom border to expand it.

Comment: I see it: Mar 25 15:20:23 Bill-Norman itunesstored[111] <Warning>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to www.myserver.com" UserInfo=0x145db5de0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to www.myserver.com, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=404} -- not sure I can make sense of it though. Does it tell you anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73813/discussion-between-paulw11-and-bill-norman).

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. It turns out that the MIME types for .ipa and .plist somehow disappeared from the IIS's list of MIME types. Therein lies another troubling problem -- how the heck did that happen?

Thanks for your time, Paulw11.

Comment: Thanks a lot for beauty answer. Solved my problem.

Comment: can you tell briefly how to add the MIME types to .iPA and .plist

Comment: @HariNarayanan - It's done through the Internet Information Services (IIS) manager. In IIS, click on a site in the left (Connections) column, find the MIME Types icon in the middle space, and double click. It will show a list of the MIME types associated with the site. In the upper right corner under "Actions" click on "Add..." The rest ought to be intuitive. Sorry I can't be more explicit, but I hope this helps! This has been so long ago that I wasn't sure I could remember how it's done.

Comment: Yes yes  @bill Norman it's really helpful to me.
And I also solve the issue by set the mime settings to both the files. Thank you so much.

Comment: Very glad to help!